# Could not set the selected property. unspecified error. knockoutJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, knockout.js

I'm using VS2010 on windows XP, Jquery-1.7.1.min.js, knockout-2.1.0.js, my browser is IE8.
trying to make a simple biding with array and :

here is the code:

```
//my.js:
$(function () {
   function tvm() {
     // Array
     this.tickets = [
        { name: 'A', price: 125 },
        { name: 'B', price: 128 },
        { name: 'C', price: 145 }
     ];
     // this will hold the selected value
     this.chosenTicket = ko.observable();
   }
   ko.applyBindings(new tvm());
});

//html:
<select
   data-bind="options: tickets,
          optionsCaption:'choose...',
          optionsText: 'name',
          value: chosenTicket">
</select>

<p data-bind="with: chosenTicket">
   <b data-bind="text: name"></b>
   <b data-bind="text: price"></b>
</p>
```

when running this I can see the select element with its data(until now everything good), when try to select a value from the select  element I get the following error message:
**"Could not set the selected property. unspecified error"**

Any idea how to fix this problem?(couldn't find help on the forums),

Comment: Your code http://jsfiddle.net/baQxf/1/ is working file on Win7 with using IE8.

Comment: ... and Chrome, FireFox, IE - under windows 8.

Comment: yes, I try it on win8 with chrom, safari, ie9, works great!!
but with the winXP :( ,  maybe the org is running some kind of policy

Comment: I tried it with IE6 on XP with no error. I'll try IE8/XP when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

Check the jsFiddle for the same **http://jsfiddle.net/rupesh_kokal/wPzNQ/**

The code what you have written works fine with the latest from knockout js.

You might want to cross-check the version of jsFiddle once.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating same in a demo sample outside VS environment with the latest version then try to replicate in VS environment.